# Extract Oracle column with CLOB datatype using SSIS

Tags: oracle, ssis, oledb, clob

I am trying to extract data from an oracle table which has a column with CLOB datatype.(MaxLenth = 33974)

I am using oracle provider for oledb to connect to the oracle db.

The table has around 200k records.

The performance is too slow.(IT TAKES 3 HOURS AND ABOVE, without the CLOB column it takes 7 minutes to complete)

When I use the Microsoft OLEDB provider for oracle, it throws "DATATYPE NOT SUPPORTED" error on the CLOB column.(I cant convert the clob to another datatype due to the business requirement)

Can someone please suggest an efficient way to load CLOB data into sql server using SSIS.

Comment: Please edit your question and include information on A) how big are the CLOBs? B) How slow is "too slow"? C) What error does the MS OLEDB For Oracle provider throw (exact text)? Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis: I have edited my question, please let me know if anymore info  if is needed, appreciate your help

Comment: You will probably have to use Oracle's own driver.

Comment: @Ciarán, could you please elaborate about which driver you are talking about? A link or two might help as well, thanks for your help

Comment: The Oracle Data Access Client is called ODP.Net and you download and install it from Oracle's site. It's easy enough to find a wealth of information about it if you do a google search. I can't answer your question further as I don't know what versions you are using nor how you are handling data in SSIS. Are you using Script tasks or Data Flow? What are you doing with the CLOB objects? etc etc etc.

Comment: That is the only provider I haven’t tried yet. I am using data flow task to load data from oracle source to sql server destination. No transformation in between. The source query returns 180k rows and one of the column is clob. Version: VS 2010 and Sql server 2012 , oracle is 10g. I am just trying to find what advantage odp.net provider has over oracle Oledb or ms Oledb for oracle provider, I couldn’t find anything substantial so I didn’t take the odd.net

Comment: TWill odp.net provider increase the performance in this scenario?The Oledb providers didn’t help neither did ado.net

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you get it worked. Help needed.